# display all records on outer join

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have one table where for a particular  project, dates for 9 months are stored (given below)

```
01-01-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-02-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-03-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-04-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-05-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-06-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-07-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-08-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
01-09-13    50036    027490101    WO12PS00003
```

i have and another table where the weight is present only for few months.i want the final output to be like (to display all months and wt as 0 for those where data is not present in the second table)

```
  projec     sl      tech_no      mon    yr      wt         ident    dt
027490101    35    WO12PS00003    01    2014    200        50036    01-01-13
027490101    35    WO12PS00003    02    2014    0          50036    01-02-13
027490101    35    WO12PS00003    09    2013    107        50036    01-03-13
027490101    35    WO12PS00003    10    2013    0          50036    01-04-13
027490101    35    WO12PS00003    11    2013    0          50036    01-05-13
027490101    36    WO12PS00003    02    2014    200        50036    01-06-13
027490101    36    WO12PS00003    12    2013    400        50036    01-07-13
027490101    77    WO12PS00003    11    2013    0          50036    01-08-13
027490101    77    WO12PS00003    12    2013    3321       50036    01-09-13
```

my query was:

```
select a.projec,sl,a.tech_no,a.mon,a.yr,nvl(sum(a.wt),0) plan_sum ,b.ident,b.dt
  from pp_init_plan a,pp_mon b 
 where a.projec=b.projec 
   and a.sl=b.sl 
   and and to_Char(b.dt(+),'yyyy')=yr 
   and to_char(b.dt(+),'mm') =a.mon
group by a.projec,a.slno,a.tech_no,a.mon,a.yr,b.ident,b.dt 
order by a.tech_no,a.mon,a.yr,b.ident,b.dt
```

It did not work! Just returned the matching records.
please help!Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL92 syntax for clarity:

```sql
select
  a.projec, a.sl, a.tech_no, a.mon, a.yr
, nvl(a.wt,0) plan_sum, b.ident, b.dt
from pp_init_plan a
right join pp_mon b
on a.projec=b.projec
  and a.sl=b.sl
  and to_char(b.dt,'yyyy')=a.yr
  and to_char(b.dt,'mm')  =a.mon;
```